# Another content type for xml files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

I want to implement an extension that echance productivity on our product. It's basically a framework for web applications that has it's own language based on XML.

First I want to classify framework specific files and perform some work that is outside of the scope of the question.

I'm new to the addins development but I think I need a custom content type for the framework specific xml files.

Every xml files in the project has a root element `<view>` and an attribute `name` that equals the the filename(without extension). (e.g the xml file ViewName.xml will look like the following)

```
<view name="ViewName">
...
</view>
```

Is it possible to assign a content type to the file based on it's contents so that the xml file will get "customxml" content type only when it contains root element `<view>` with the `name` equals to the filename?